# Failing to connect to Apple Time capsule

Tags: 10.04, wireless, ubuntu-netbook

I have just installed 10.04 Netbook Remix i386 on my Asus eee pc 901 and it's failing to connect to my Apple Time Capsule wireless network.

It will connect (and remain connected) to other wireless networks but not my own home setup using the Capsule. It sees the Time Capsule, accepts the login password but doesn't actually connect.

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!